# How to deal with non invertible matrix in survival analysis

Tags: python, survival-analysis, cox-regression, lifelines

I am new to survival analysis. I tried to using `CoxPHFitter`, But I came across this error. `numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Matrix is singular.`

After went through this error, I came to know **one of my column has non invertible matrix.**

So what should I do now? Can't I use that column? If So, What is the conclusion I can come up with that column?

Full stack trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "surv_model.py", line 79, in 
>       cph.fit(X, 'T', event_col='label')
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lifelines/fitters/coxph_fitter.py", line 165, in fit
>       step_size=step_size)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lifelines/fitters/coxph_fitter.py", line 253, in _newton_rhaphson
>       inv_h_dot_g_T = spsolve(-h, g.T, sym_pos=True)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 251, in solve
>       _solve_check(n, info)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/basic.py", line 31, in _solve_check
>       raise LinAlgError('Matrix is singular.')
>   numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: Matrix is singular.

I'm using python [`lifelines`](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quickstart.html#survival-regression)

Comment: Add a regularisation parameter: 0.01

Comment: @coldspeed - thanks for the comment. I'm new to lifelines. can you provide an example? where should I keep this parameter? Can you share a link related to this?

Comment: Actually, let me think about that once more. Invertibility is solved in linear regression using regularisation. Not sure the same concepts apply here. How about posting an [mcve] of the code used?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah something like `cph = CoxPHFitter(penalizer=0.01)`

Comment: However, singular matrices are usually caused by multilinear data, i.e a problem with your input data. Read more about it here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86269/what-is-the-effect-of-having-correlated-predictors-in-a-multiple-regression-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of a matrix, which always exists. But be aware that in case of non-invertible matrices, this is only a least-squares fit to the optimal solution.

Re-thinking your problem, the comments are correct: Add a regularization parameter. This actually seems to be a known problem: https://github.com/sebp/scikit-survival/issues/28#issuecomment-370918386

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am using `lifelines`. this error comes from internal method provided by lifelines from coxphfitter? how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR:

I think your problem might be solved using the `penalizer` input argument of the `CoxPHFitter()` class that you are using in your question. You might solve your issue by just copying the following line.

```
cph = CoxPHFitter(penalizer=0.01)
```

You can read a bit more in the  [documentation for the model](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitters/regression/CoxPHFitter.html).

## Longer explanation:

Since the Cox Proportional Hazard algorithm is, at it's core, a linear regression, it assumes that the input features are not related. If we are estimating the coefficients of many features, the standard CoxPH model may fall apart when trying to invert the non-singular matrix due to correlation among features.

Adding this `penalizer` parameter serves as the regularization parameter mentioned in one of the comments above.

In case someone else comes to this question but they are using `scikit-survival`, the input argument that they are looking for is `alpha`. Not to be mistaken with the `alpha` parameter found in `lifelines` implementation of the CoxPH algorithm which serves as the level in the confidence intervals.